# Jquery table inherit height of containing td

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint

How would i use jquery to set the height of each .ms-cal-tweekitem to the rendered height of .ms-cal-eworkday. This is in a share point calender and i am not allowed to edit the ASPX :(.

Sharepoint is using rowspan to change the height of each event but the contained tables are not expanding to fill it height:100% dosent seem to work.

```
<td class="ms-cal-eworkday" rowspan="8"> 
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="ms-cal-tweekitem" dir="" style="background-color: rgb(6, 92, 165);">
<tbody><tr>
    <td valign="top" href="/schools/ecclesfield/newdemosite/minibus-booking/Lists/Minibus/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">
     <div>
      <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width="50" height="1" alt=""><br>
      <img src="/_layouts/images/recursml.gif" class="ms-cal-hidden" alt="" align="absmiddle">
      <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" class="ms-cal-dayitem" href="/schools/ecclesfield/newdemosite/minibus-booking/Lists/Minibus/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self" tabindex="5">
        <nobr>03:00 PM</nobr>
        <br>
        <b>test3</b>
        <br>
        YS12 NHT
        </a>
     </div>
     </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody></table>
</td>
```

Thanks

Lewis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples:

```
 var ms-cal-eworkdayHeight = $('.ms-cal-eworkday').height();
 $('.ms-cal-tweekitem').height(ms-cal-eworkdayHeight);
```

You could also do:

```
 var ms-cal-eworkdayHeight = $('.ms-cal-eworkday').outerHeight();
 $('.ms-cal-tweekitem').height(ms-cal-eworkdayHeight);
```

`outerHeight()` will return the height plus any padding or margin.